# How to run deployment groups on a virtual machine?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

I want to run a deployment groups on my virtual machine.

I have run my registration script (PowerShell), but it shows the error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote name could not be resolved:
'vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net'"
At line:1 char:1303
+ ... nalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Typ ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I found in [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) that I need to pass `--proxyurl`, `--proxyusername` and `--proxypassword` in the script.

```
./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "myuser" --proxypassword "mypass"
```

But I don't know what value to fill in, especially the URL.

I tried to copy this script and put it in my registration script, but the same error still occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using this on your office network or wherever the internet connection requires proxy, and that may have proxy settings, then you can get the proxy url from the Internet proxy settings. Creds has to be supplied if it uses a proxy username/pwd.

The below info may not be ideal for everyone, so don't blame me for this solution but this is what worked for me and for my need.

**Note: THIS HAS TO HAVE ATTENTION AND UTMOST CARE IF YOU'RE RUNNING ON A SERVER**

- you may copy the ps scripts to a notepad,
- do the steps manually on the designated server.
- Download the agent zip file from web
- extract it
- copy the contents to the A# folder that you want to setup, mostly A1
- run the config.cmd line from the ps script which would expect the appropriate creds that you need to make sure to supply as token

If you have appropriate permissions, it will go forward and install the agent on the respective server and prompt you for further steps like tags etc.

**UPDATE**:

1. I didn't have enough permissions to create the Deployment group but rather, just a deployment item (VM)
2. So I created the Deployment group manually from the deployment target. I had issues when creating it but going backwards by creating a group from the target was successful for me.